# How can I make a method function inside a subclass inherit some properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Trying to build a discord.js bot I ran into some mental gap.
Let's say I need my `console application` to be a puppy that does a trick and barks after that. So I would build a subclass for this in this fashion:

```js
class MyPuppy extends Dog {

  constructor() {
    super({
      name: 'Fido'
    });
  }

  trick() {
    console.log(`- Gives paw -`);
  }

}
```

But this wouldn't make the application to bark. For that I assume the `trick()` function would need to inherit some methods although I'm not an expert in Javascript.
My intuition tells me that I would need to declare the `parent class` somewhat like this:

```js
class Dog {

  constructor(props) {
    this.name = props.name;
    this.trick = () => {
      this.trick.prototype.bark = () => {
        console.log('Woof!')
      };
    };
  }

}
```

But as this isn't working and I don't know what else is necessary to implement this behavior, this has stopped me to continue learning `Node.js`. Would you have any advice on this application?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you never instantiate `MyPuppy` and call the `trick` function of course it won't print anything.

Comment: I'm trying to have the `trick()` method log both `- Gives paw -` and then `Woof!` bark. Sorry, I didn't executed the `.trick()` method as my question is about prototypes, I'll edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried invoking the `bark` method from within the `trick` method?

```js
class Dog {
    constructor(props) {
        this.name = props.name;
    }

    bark() {
        console.log("Woof!");
    }
}

class MyPuppy extends Dog {
    constructor() {
        super({
            name: 'Fido'
        });
    }

    trick() {
        console.log(`- Gives paw -`);
        this.bark();
    }
}

const puppy = new MyPuppy()
puppy.trick()
```

Another way to look at this would be to add the default `trick` behaviour inside the parent class and then execute the parent's `trick` method in all children's `trick` methods.

```js
class Dog {
    constructor(props) {
        this.name = props.name;
    }

    bark() {
        console.log("Woof!");
    }

    trick() {
        this.bark();
    }
}

class MyPuppy extends Dog {
    constructor() {
        super({
            name: 'Fido'
        });
    }

    trick() {
        console.log(`- Gives paw -`);
        super.trick();
    }
}

new MyPuppy().trick()
```

Comment: This really helps, thank you! Although I'm trying to have the `trick()` method add the bark without having to invoke it in the `extended class MyPuppy`. My application needs to have the `console.log('- Gives paw -')` inside `trick()` and then bark without asking. Do you how this could be achieved?

Comment: I am not sure how you can automatically run the parent's `bark` method in the child's `trick` method, but if you want some default behaviour for a trick, define it in the parent's `trick` method and execute `super.trick()` in the `trick` method of the child. This way, all the default `trick` stuff is handled in a central place in the parent's `trick` method and all classes extending this parent, can just use `super.trick()` in their implementation to get the default `trick` behaviour. I have updated the answer to show this approach as well.